# vout value in createrawtransaction

Tags: bitcoin-cli, createrawtransaction

I have been following the [Bitcoin Core tutorial on creating a simple raw transaction](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-raw-transaction) from an offline computer using the CLI.

The part on [`createrawtransaction`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#createrawtransaction) indicates that the raw transaction should have a `vout` value:

> The output index number (vout) of the outpoint; the first output in a
>   transaction is index 0

Therefore, if there is only one outpoint, its `vout` value should be 0.

**However, [`createrawtransaction`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#createrawtransaction) only works with `vout=1`, even though I have only one `txid` in the command - what am I missing here?**

Comment: Can you post the transaction id of the output you are trying to use to create the transaction? If the unspent output has a vout=0, it should work just fine with `createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"6aeSomeTxId", "vout":0}]' '{"1SomeOtherAddress":0.01,"1changeAddress":0.05}'`

Comment: Are you using the vout of the transaction you're spending or the transaction you're creating? It should be the vout of the outpoint you're spending.